# Identify marker selection using NMAMapViewDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, marker

I am working on here `map` and stuck while identifying, which marker is selected by user.

I am using `NMAMapViewDelegate` and won't be able to find out which method is used to identify the particular `marker selection`.

Answer (score 0):

Please set break point to the following method and check :

```
(void) mapView:( NMAMapView *) mapView didSelectObjects:(NSArray *) objects
```

May be it will help you....

Comment: func mapView(_ mapView: NMAMapView!, didSelect objects: [Any]!) 

Have tried this but still unable to identify which marker is selected.